# Is the Inverse of the Vectorised Solid Angle Equation for $n$ Circular Discs Continuous?

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, regression, elliptic-integrals, solid-angle

I have a continuous function$^{*1}$ that takes in 3 arguments, and returns 24 outputs. I want to know if the inverse of this function is continuous.

The 3 input arguments are the x, y, and z position of a particle in 3D space within an array of circular discs, and the 24 outputs are the solid angles subtended by the 24 discs, as shown in the picture bellow.

[image: an 18 detector array]
*(This picture shows 18 detectors, the 24 are in a similar arrangement: 2 layers of 4$\times$3)*

$$$$

The equation for the solid angle for each disk is given by [this paper](http://www.umich.edu/~ners312/Course%20Library/SolidAngleOfADiskOffAxis.pdf). The equations are shown bellow:

\begin{align} \Omega &= 2\pi - \frac{2L}{R_{max}}K(k) - \pi\Lambda_{0}(\xi , k) &for\;\; r_0 > r_m\label{eq:elliptic1}\\[10pt] &= \pi - \frac{2L}{R_{max}} K(k) &for\;\; r_0 = r_m\label{eq:elliptic2}\\[10pt] &= - \frac{2L}{R_{max}} K(k) + \pi\Lambda_{0}(\xi , k) &for\;\; r_0 < r_m\label{eq:elliptic3} \end{align}

I've inputted 2000 random particle locations and then used the results from these equations to train a Neural Network.  This Neural Network was trained using the 24 solid angles as its inputs, and the position of the particle in 3D space as its outputs.

This means the Neural Network approximates a function that takes in 24 inputs, and returns 3 outputs (x, y, and z positions).

What I want to know is: **Is the function that is being approximated a continuous function?**

Is there even a way to know this for certainty? Any answer or comment is very much appreciated.

Thanks!

---

*$^{*1}$ Only continuous if the particle is within the array of discs. This can be taken to be always true for the application I am using this for.*

Comment: It's not even clear to me that the inverse function is well defined. Given the 24 angles, can you always get some $(x,y,z)$ point? And is this point unique?

Comment: "Is this point unique". I'm pretty certain it is. For a single disc there will be multiple $(x,y,z)$ points that give the same angle, but for multiple discs I imagine that there is only one point for every unique set of angles. "Can you always get some $(x,y,z)$ point?". This is what I really need to know. For each $(x,y,z)$ point you can always get 24 angles, but I have no clue if the inverse is true.

Comment: I understand that this question isn't very good, so I'd also appreciate it if someone could tell me a better way to ask it. I study engineering, not maths, so I'm not sure if the question title describes the question very well. I really need to find the answer, so i'm considering putting a bounty on this question. I'd like to improve the way i'm asking it before I do though.

Comment: You want to ask if the inverse function is well-defined, not whether it's continuous. Or, jusy forget about function and inverse jargon. Just ask it as follows: given the 24 angles, is there a corresponding point $(x,y,z)$, and it it unique.

Comment: My intuition says that it's not true -- I would guess that there are plenty of 24-tuples that don't have any corresponding point(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, let's consider a single disk $D$ and its solid angle value, $\theta$. Look at the locus of points in 3D that give this angle value with this disk. This locus is some sort of surface $S(D,\theta)$ in 3D space. It might even be a sphere, actually. Probably not. But it doesn't matter.

Now take three such disks $D_1, D_2, D_3$ and their solid angles $\theta_1, \theta_2, \theta_3$. In order to satisfy our conditions, a point $P$ must lie on all three of the surfaces $S(D_1, \theta_1)$, $S(D_2, \theta_2)$, $S(D_3, \theta_3)$. In other words, the point $P$ must be a point of intersection of the three surfaces. Generally, you would expect 3 surfaces in 3D to intersect in only a finite number of points, unless they have some special dependency relationship, so there are only a finite number of possibilities for $P$.

Now add a fourth disk. To me, it seems highly unlikely that its locus surface would pass through any of the points of intersection of the first three locus surfaces.

Saying it more briefly ... it seems highly unlikely that the 24 surfaces $S(D_i,\theta_i)$ will have any common points of intersection.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This is very interesting. At any height z above a single disk, a point will subtend the same angle when moved around a circular path centered on the disks axis. The point will also subtend the same angle when it is moved both closer to the disk along the z axis and further from the disk axis. I've been drawing out what this surface would look like and I think it is a sphere (or a hemisphere as i'm not including points below the disk). So the 24 surfaces are unlikely to have any common points of intersection unless the disks are really close together (which they're not).

Comment: What does this mean for the Neural Network (A Neural Network is basically a function approximator, which uses a cost function and regression) I've created this Neural Network and it can narrow down the position of the point to within 0.1m of a 3mx12mx4m array, so it does work, i'm just now trying to understand why it works. If the function it is approximating is not well-defined shouldn't this mean that it shouldn't work?

Comment: This is just a guess ... I suppose your inputs to the neural network are angle values that come from physical measurements. So, you are not using the entire 24-D space of angles as inputs, you are only using a very small subset. And, for this subset, the neural network calculation works. If you give it a set of angles that don't correspond to any 3D point, I suppose it will return an approximation that is "best" in some sense.